# perl socket event driven programming

Tags: perl

I am writing a perl server which authenticates client using public and private key and eventually it turns out I need $client_socket->recv to be event driven rather polling in infinite loop. Is there build in code to perform event driven with IO::Socket::INET.

```
while(1)
{
    # waiting for a new client connection
    my $client_socket = $socket->accept();

    # get information about a newly connected client
    my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
    my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
    print "connection from $client_address:$client_port\n";

    # read up to 1024 characters from the connected client
    my $data = "";
    $client_socket->recv($data, 1024);
    print "received data: $data\n";

    # write response data to the connected client
    $client_socket->send("some response text");

    # notify client that response has been sent
    shutdown($client_socket, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Perl does not have anything for event-driven programming built in. There are various modules to do event-driven development on CPAN. Some of them are listed in [Task::Kensho::Async](https://metacpan.org/pod/Task::Kensho::Async).

The most famous ones are [POE](https://metacpan.org/pod/POE) and [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent). But you might want to look at [IO::Async](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async) specifically.

Comment: I've not included samples here because I've never really used either of them and don't have the time right now to try.

Comment: so do you suggest that I should rely on polling for data and how do i handle the new incoming connection, coz there might be number of my own defined handshake with clients. Is this the robust way of doing ? I don't want to end up with nodejs.

Comment: @Sagar No, simbabque suggested you use one of the above modules to provide an event loop. (That said, perl has built-in tools to build event loops, mainly `select`.)

Comment: This list from AnyEvent is more comprehensive: "AnyEvent - the DBI of event loop programming.

EV, Event, Glib, Tk, UV, Perl, Event::Lib, Irssi, rxvt-unicode, IO::Async, Qt, FLTK and POE are various supported event loops/environments."

Comment: Yyeah, I don't really agree with that description. AnyEvent is nothing like DBI. I wouldn't use AnyEvent (in fact, I'd avoid all modules by this particular author).

Comment: It wasn't about the description, but since you bring it up: DBI is a driver-independent interface to a host of drivers. AnyEvent is an event-loop-independent interface to a host of event loops. /// I know what you mean about the author!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your precious time.